# How can I loop through consecutive file directories?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I'm in directory a. Under directory a there is a fixed directory b. There are d{091....099} directories under the b directory. There are also different *.gz files under this d directory. I need to extract data from these files (filenames) and print them one after the other.

i have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find . -name "*.gz"); do
  file=$(basename ${file})
       echo ${file:0:4} | tee -a receiver_ids > log
       echo ${file:16:17} | tee -a doy > log2
       echo ${file:0:100} | tee -a data_record > log3
done
cut -c 1-3 < doy > doy2
cut -c 1-23 < data_record > summary_name
```

but by doing this, the files are processed in an unordered way. this is what i get from,

```
cat data_record
ISTA00TUR_R_20190940000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190990000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190970000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190920000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190980000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190910000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190960000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190930000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
ISTA00TUR_R_20190950000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: What's the target OS? You might need specific extensions for processing your files while sorting them by filename. BTW, `for f in $(...)` is a broken construct, don't use it

Comment: I am trying to write bash code on shell. I am connecting via server. ubuntu is used but I don't know its version.

Comment: Are you sure that you want `log`,`log2` and `log3` to only contain the last processed file? Also, do `receiver_ids`, `doy` and `data_record` really need to keep the result of the last run of the script?

Answer (score 1):

"the files are processed in an unordered way" -- maybe it is because the command `find ...` does not give the results in the order you want.

How about this

```
for file in b/d*/*gz; do
  ...
done
```

or

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.gz" | sort); do
  ...
done
```

By the way, if I were you, I would not use the name `file`, because there is a program called `file`, easy to get confused.

Comment: i have already tried the first but i didn't worked. the second one is work! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**As you're running Ubuntu, I assume that you have access to the GNU version of the standard tools.**</sub>

It seems like you want to sort your **filepaths** by **filename**. It's a little complicated but here's a way to do the task robustly and somewhat efficiently:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

find . -name '*.gz' -printf '%f\0' |
sort -z |
while IFS='' read -r -d '' fname
do
    printf '%s\n' "${fname:0:4}" >&3
    printf '%s\n' "${fname:16:17}" >&4
    printf '%s\n' "${fname:0:100}" >&5
done \
   3> >(tee -a receiver_ids > log) \
   4> >(tee -a doy > log2) \
   5> >(tee -a data_record > log3)
```

**explanations:**

- The `-printf '%f\0'` predicate of GNU `find` will output a stream of `NUL`-delimited **filenames** (i.e. without the leading directory path)
- GNU `sort -z` will sort the `NUL`-delimited filenames
- bash's `while IFS='' read -r -d '' fname` loads each `NUL`-delimited filename into the variable `fname`.
- Then I define a few file descriptors (`3`,`4` and `5`) for the `while ...; do ...; done` loop, each one being bound to a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html); the purpose is to get rid of the forks inside the loop (which are horribly slow).

Comment: Thank you very much for this descriptive answer. It got a lot better and made me understand better. Thanks again.